# Finding your 'pornstar name' by combining, e.g. your first pet's name and your mother's maiden name. Was this originally a form of phishing?

Tags: phishing

It worked like this -- you were at a party and each person said their first pet's name, e.g.  'Binky' and their mother's maiden name 'Robinson' and the (supposedly hilarious) result was the 'pornstar' name Binkie Robinson.  Making the animal and the person specific always seemed pretty pointless to me as far as the game was concerned because most pet names combined with a surname will give this humorous effect.

Therefore, right from the start I wondered if this was simply a phishing attempt because of course people often use those things as passwords or recovery information.

My bank asks account holders to provide a security password for identification when phoning them. By default they ask for 'your mother's maiden name'. Some well-known websites have a 'secret' password-recovery question that is 'What was the name of your first pet.'

Quite recently I have heard people playing this game on buses and even TV shows so it's still around.

**Questions**

1. Is there any evidence or even suspicion that this originated as a phishing scam? Have I been paranoid about it all this time for nothing?
2. There are websites that present this as a game -- are they likely to be phishing?
3. If a website gathers this information does it pose a serious risk to anyone's data security?
4. I phoned into a radio station once because the DJ was playing this game every week with his celebrity guests. I tried to point out the risk but they didn't even understand the concept of what I was talking about. They obviously thought I was a crank and afterwards I started to doubt myself! Who is nuts? Me or them?

Comment: The question is mighty unclear. Porn stars, web sites, animals are mixed together in one horrific incomprehensible jumble. What are you asking, once again?

Comment: Such kind of information is usually already available in some public place or another. The risk does not lie in such game or radio show, the risk lies in websites using poor authentication systems allowing attackers to steal people's accounts. If you were to contact someone, it should be the such websites owners so they implement more secure systems in order to handle their users account in a more responsible way.

Comment: Phishing involves sending an email which is not the case of the scenario you described. As for game websites, yes, they are targeted by attacker ([read this report of Symantec](http://www.symantec.com/connect/articles/security-11-part-5-online-gaming-fraud-scam-and-phishing-attempts)). There's quite too little an attacker can do with the information you described as long as you do not provide both sensitive and personal info such as credit card numbers, passwords, birthdates ... But yes, as you can read from the link above,  there are famous game website where phishing and scamming were played

Comment: This does not qualify as phishing and nothing private is disclosed. I think you have a number of inaccurate assumptions feeding a little paranoia.

Comment: I understand what the user is asking. This kind of thing goes on on social media all the time. It will have things like come up with your silly name using your birthdate. and you pick the first name for the month and second name for the date. Then someone can easily look at the silly name you post and they know your birthday. Could it be phishing? possibly. Even if not, it would make it easier for someone to find out info if you participate in such things.

Comment: #1 is arguably academic/historical, though interesting. #2 involves speculation. The sites may run off ad revenue, they may be freely hosted -- if they're not... it's hard to say why someone would pay to host them. SEO something? I can only speculate. You could flesh out this question perhaps separately? #3 Does it pose a risk? Sure. Credit reporting agencies verify using that stuff. And so do banks, even if you mitigate exposure by using false, hard-to-crack strings in prompts you control. Finally, you're asking security.stackexchange if you're paranoid? The answer is no, you're not... ever!